# Exception in google console: Exception com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.ct

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-services, google-developers-console

I’m currently working on a Flutter application. When I uploaded my app to play.google.com/console and Google ran the initial pre-launch report I get this error:

Logical.txt:

> at tk_trace.Broadcast to com.google.android.apps.search.googleapp.permissions.udcdataservice.facs.FacsBroadcastReceiver_Receiver com.google.android.gms.udc.action.FACS_CACHE_UPDATED_EXPLICIT(Unknown Source:0)
>
> Exception com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.ct: at tk_trace.Broadcast to com.google.android.apps.search.googleapp.permissions.udcdataservice.facs.FacsBroadcastReceiver_Receiver com.google.android.gms.udc.action.FACS_CACHE_UPDATED_EXPLICIT(Unknown Source:0)
> Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.m: 20: The connection to Google Play services was lost due to service disconnection.
> at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ad.a (SourceFile:16)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.bk.b (SourceFile:179)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.bk.a (SourceFile:167)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.aa.a (SourceFile:2)
> at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.f.handleMessage (SourceFile:38)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
> at com.google.android.gms.j.c.b.c.a (SourceFile:5)
> at com.google.android.gms.j.c.b.c.dispatchMessage (SourceFile:4)
> at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:67)

The error occurs on a Google Pixel 5 Android 11 (SDK 30). It only happens in the Google console. I’ve tried to replicate the error on an emulatorIve tried to run the app locally on an emulator with the same specifics as the one where the crash occurred in google (all parameteres the same). I see nothing unexpected happening doing this.  It's an older app which Ive updated the packages for. This error has not occurred before.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?